# How to run fsck on an external drive with OS X?

Tags: macos, fsck

I'm getting this error when trying to repartition an external drive:  "".

I want to run `fsck -fy` on the drive, but don't know the proper syntax for doing it on an external drive?

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 41):

Actually you want to do:

`% sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s1` (depending on what partition you want to check).

It won't work with just `fsck` you have to put `fsck_hfs` as the command to run.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Before you run it, List all your disks with `diskutil list`  My SD card is disk2.  Then you want to find the partition number, so do something like `ls /dev/disk2*`.  This results in `disk2s1`.  So the final command I run is this `sudo fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk2s1`.   NOTE: I purposly formatted my SD card as hfs.  Normally they are using like fat or something.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm getting this error when trying to repartition an external drive: ""

That's a very descriptive error indeed.

---

In order to run `fsck` on an external drive, you first need to find out the identifier of the drive. Run `diskutil list` and check the name of the volume listed under `IDENTIFIER` – it'll be something like `disk3s4`, for example.

Use that name to run `fsck`. You can also pass the `-f` option to force checking a clean filesystem.

```
sudo fsck /dev/disk3s4
```

`fsck` has shorthands for diverse file system types:

- `fsck_hfs` for HFS, use the `-f` option to force checking journaled systems
- `fsck_exfat` for ExFAT (no `-f` option here)
- `fsck_msdos` for FAT (no `-f` option here)

Comment: Actually, it looks like as of 10.9, you can't use `fsck` without some sort of flag.  Using the command as given here results in the help/usage output.

Comment: See Paul’s answer - you have to use `fsck_hfs`.

Comment: (8 years later) and `fsck_apfs` for modern APFS drives

Answer (score 2):

I had to run with the -l flag:

```
diskutil list # find your identifier
/sbin/fsck_hfs -l -f /dev/disk16
```

The `-l` flag tells fsck to check the drive in read only mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the original question, but closely related.

Another option is to use diskutil itself to verify or repair an external drive.
I'm not sure how it compares to fsck, but it fixed my external drive that was not mounting after I accidentally left it plugged in during a restart for a system update.

```
diskutil list  # to find the IDENTIFIER
  (some internal disks listed first)
  /dev/disk2 (external, physical):                                              
    #:                    TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:   GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2     
    1:                     EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1   
    2:               Apple_HFS FreeAgent GoFlex Drive  499.8 GB   disk2s2
```

and then commands such as

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk2
diskutil verifyVolume disk2s1
diskutil verifyVolume disk2s2
```

For some reason just running the verify commands solved my issue, but if you need to go further there are also repair commands:

```
diskutil repairDisk disk2
diskutil repairVolume disk2s1
diskutil repairVolume disk2s2
```